# Having trouble using rand() function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server all I want to do is select one field and assign a random number to each row. There will be over 1M rows, and I will then order by the random numbers to select the top 50K as a random sample.

If i do:

```
Select x, rand()*(50000-1)+1) 
From Y
```

I get all of the x that I want, but they each have the same random number.

Comment: Just remember to take out the parenthesis after "+1" if you're not using FLOOR or something else when you're generating your number.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to assign any values, just order by a pseudo-random value and take the `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 50000 X FROM Y ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you briefly explain how this works? NewID is new to me

Comment: @user6114185: `NEWID()` returns a GUID, so a new GUID is assigned temporary on each row so the `ORDER BY` works. Since GUIDs are, for all intents and purposes, guaranteed to never repeat, and they aren't generated sequentially anyway, we can basically trust that it will be random enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the random number to sort randomly, you could instead skip the random number field and use

```
ORDER BY NEWID()
```